# NLTK pos tagger is creating different tags for the same word. Can anybody explain this?

Tags: nlp, nltk, pos-tagger, nltk-book

The word RR is tagged as NN in one case and NNP in another. Also applicant is tagged as NN in one case and JJ in another. Why is this difference on the same word ? Shouldn't anything starting with a capital letter be tagged as NNP ?

```
testb
Out[45]: 
['applicant',
 'applicant',
 'applicant',
 'applicant',
 'RR',
 'RR',
 'Khan',
 'he',
 'how',
 'let',
 'she',
 'that',
 'there',
 'what',
 'where',
 'firm']

[nltk.pos_tag([i]) for i in testb]
Out[46]: 
[[('applicant', 'NN')],
 [('applicant', 'NN')],
 [('applicant', 'NN')],
 [('applicant', 'NN')],
 [('RR', 'NN')],
 [('RR', 'NN')],
 [('Khan', 'NNP')],
 [('he', 'PRP')],
 [('how', 'WRB')],
 [('let', 'VB')],
 [('she', 'PRP')],
 [('that', 'IN')],
 [('there', 'RB')],
 [('what', 'WP')],
 [('where', 'WRB')],
 [('firm', 'NN')]]

nltk.pos_tag(testb)
Out[47]: 
[('applicant', 'JJ'),
 ('applicant', 'NN'),
 ('applicant', 'NN'),
 ('applicant', 'JJ'),
 ('RR', 'NNP'),
 ('RR', 'NNP'),
 ('Khan', 'NNP'),
 ('he', 'PRP'),
 ('how', 'WRB'),
 ('let', 'VB'),
 ('she', 'PRP'),
 ('that', 'IN'),
 ('there', 'EX'),
 ('what', 'WP'),
 ('where', 'WRB'),
 ('firm', 'NN')]
```

Comment: depending on what tagger you use, it will consider the context the word is occuring in when making the decision what tag to use. A very good explanation can be found [here](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/10.pdf) EDIT: That's also why you should use your tagger on grammatical sentences rather than random words for good results.

Answer (score 0):

- Parts of speech assignments can differ between the same words (e.g. *the **right** man for the job* versus *he has a **right** to be angry*)
- The NLTK parser has a non-zero margin of error